# How to find the closest point in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distance

I have few locations from table A and one location from table B. I want to find the name from the row from table A with the closest location to location from table B.
My code:

```
    select 
    id, ST_Distance(
(select the_geom from task where id = 15), //tableB
(select location from place where address = 'addressFromTableA1')) as p1,

ST_Distance((select the_geom from task where id = 15), //tableB
(select location from place where address = 'addressFromTableA2')) as p2
from table
where id = 10;
```

It gives me one row with many distances columns, but how to get many distances in one column ? I imagine that I can select my neded informations and distances and select MIN.

Or maybe some loop, which gives me some min value..

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a join as needed and take the first row only.

```
select 
    B.id, A.*, ST_Distance(B.the_geom, A.location) dist
from task B 
join place A on B.id = 10
order by ST_Distance(B.the_geom, A.location) desc
limit 1;
```